# Can you include logic in youtube-dl's --output parameter?

Tags: bash, youtube-dl

For `youtube-dl`, I have a [script](https://github.com/TheFrenchGhosty/TheFrenchGhostys-Ultimate-YouTube-DL-Scripts-Collection/blob/master/scripts/Archivist%20Scripts/Archivist%20Scripts%20(No%20Comments)/Playlists/Playlists.sh) that has an `--output` value that looks like:

```
"%(uploader)s/%(playlist_title)s/%(upload_date)s - %(title)s/%(upload_date)s - %(title)s [%(id)s].%(ext)s"
```

Sometimes I download individual videos, not playlists or channels; I'd like to use the same script. Is there a way to put an `if` statement or some other logical expression to say "ignore the playlist title if there isn't one" instead of it defaulting to `"NA"`?

Comment: Why do you want to use a script written for playlists if you aren't downloading playlists?

Comment: Because the difference between the "playlist" version and the "not-playlist" version is mostly a matter of `--output`. I can adjust that easily; I'm mainly wondering about how versatile the `--output` parameter is.